# How can I get a unique list of object that have a certain relationship with another object?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a simple Larval model where a user has many posts and each post has one category. Database, migrations ans models are properly set up.

However, how can I get a list of all categories that a certain user has published posts to using Eloquent?

Comment: Hi Jeff.  This site is really meant for helping with code problems, not writing the code you.  As such, you should post what you've tried, what's wrong, research you've done, etc.  This is a link to how to ask a good question here on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please review Eloquent Relationships in the Laravel docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

The relationships between the tables are defined (as in a one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relationship) and then you will be able to query those relationships, including chaining the relationships.

For example,

```
$user->posts()->categories
```